# Help with SQL server stack dump

Tags: sql-server

We're running SQL 2005 standard SP2 on a 4cpu box. Suddenly it crashdumps, after which all pooled connections are invalid and it goes into admin-only mode (only sa can connect)

The short stackdump is below. After the dump a number of errors show up like '2008-09-16 10:49:34.48 Server      Resource Monitor (0xec4) Worker 0x03D1C0E8 appears to be non-yielding on Node 0. Memory freed: 232408 KB. Approx CPU Used: kernel 203 ms, user 140 ms, Interval: 250250.'

Have Googled around but couldn't find a definate answer. Anyone?

```
2008-09-16 10:46:24.98 Server      Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
2008-09-16 10:46:25.40 Server      **Dump thread - spid = 0, PSS = 0x00000000, EC = 0x00000000
2008-09-16 10:46:25.40 Server      ***Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0009.txt
2008-09-16 10:46:25.40 Server      * *******************************************************************************
2008-09-16 10:46:25.40 Server      *
2008-09-16 10:46:25.40 Server      * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2008-09-16 10:46:25.40 Server      *   09/16/08 10:46:25 spid 0
2008-09-16 10:46:25.42 Server      *
2008-09-16 10:46:25.42 Server      * Non-yielding Resource Monitor
2008-09-16 10:46:25.42 Server      *
2008-09-16 10:46:25.42 Server      * *******************************************************************************
2008-09-16 10:46:25.42 Server      * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2008-09-16 10:46:25.42 Server      * Short Stack Dump
2008-09-16 10:46:25.76 Server      Stack Signature for the dump is 0x00000352
2008-09-16 10:46:32.70 Server      External dump process return code 0x20000001.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How It Works: Non-Yielding Resource Monitor](http://blogs.msdn.com/psssql/archive/2008/03/28/how-it-works-non-yielding-resource-monitor.aspx) on the PSS SQL Server Engineers blog.

If this, and the linked whitepaper, don't help, then you're probably best to contact PSS (Microsoft Product Support Services) directly.